# Worst case running time in a graph with n vertices and m edges

Tags: big-o, computer-science, graph-theory

Let G be a connected graph with n vertices and m edges. Which of the following best corresponds to the notion of "linear time," when this graph is the input to an algorithm?

a) O(n)

b) O(m)

c) O(n^2)

d) O((n+m)^2)

I didn't think this question would trip me up as much as it did, but I have to figure it out now. By definition of linear time, I would assume it is either a or b. If i HAD to choose one, I would go with B, as there may be more edges then there are vertices. But, I know that may not be the case and there may be more vertices than edges, so A doesn't sound too bad either, and D is also the only one that actually takes both n and m into account.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, the answer is (b).

Note that G is a **connected** graph, so we have the following basic fact:

```
m ≥ n-1
```

Since the input to the algorithm is the graph G, the input size to the algorithm is `n + m`, and we have:

```
  n + m
≤ m - 1 + m
< 2m
```

Therefore linear time with respect to the input is `O(n + m) = O(m)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see I was on the right track, but you cleared up where I was confused and I see now exactly why it is b.